# Converting docx to PDF/A with libre office writer

Tags: pdf, docx, libreoffice, file-conversion

I am happily converting docx files to PDF via the command line (controlled via C# process calls) out of my service.

Unfortunately I could not find any internet search results on how to set the options for the output PDF that the GUI offers me. I am specifically looking for generating PDF/A and tagged PDF via the command line.

Anyone ever done this and knows how to do that?

EDIT:
Obviously getting a PDF/A can be done by using unoconv instead.
On windows one would use the following command line in a checked out unoconv repository:

```
python.exe .\unoconv -f pdf -eSelectPdfVersion=1 C:\temp\libre\renderingtest.docx
```

I did not find further information on how to select other things (tagged PDF etc.) and where to get a complete list of the options that are available.

EDIT: It seems as one could try the different options in the GUI. The settings get saved to `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\registrymodifications.xcu`. Then one can look up the changed setting and provide that to unoconv as this:

```
python.exe .\unoconv -f pdf -eUseTaggedPDF=1 -eSelectPdfVersion=1 C:\temp\libre\renderingtest.docx
```

Still not sure if I am doing this correctly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gotenberg](https://gotenberg.dev/docs/modules/libreoffice#route) project [shows](https://github.dev/gotenberg/gotenberg/blob/b76990ec16ab0c45a2b7e7f840e19c939aec5da5/pkg/modules/libreoffice/routes.go#L91) how that can be done using unocov.

```
$ curl --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/forms/libreoffice/convert' --form 'files=@"doc.docx"' --form 'nativePdfFormat="PDF/A-1a"' -o pdfA.pdf
```

[Example PDF](https://filebin.net/qaylql3tjibm37w5)

[image: enter imageenter link description here description here]