# Export writer document to PDF with another than the default PDF-version

Tags: pdf-generation, libreoffice

For a few month I am working with Libreoffice 7.4. I am trying to get a PDF with PDF-version 1.5 (because LaTeX still does not accept 1.6 for input).

I am using a command like this as described in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57513457/how-to-create-a-pdf-a-from-command-line-with-libre-office-draw-in-headless-mode?newreg=e7f2c80ed5734860a5c6df02df697c9c) by Mike Kaganski:

```
soffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export:{"SelectPdfVersion":"type":"long","value":"15"}} %1
```

where %1 is a fully qualified writer document (odt). This produces the correct pdf, but always with PDF-spec 1.6. Changing the *value* in the command to anything has no effect.

By the way, using the exact syntac as in the link, i.e. 'pdf:writer_pdf ...}}' produces not a *.pdf but a *.'pdf.

What am I doing wrongly? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, K J. Though this is not an answer to my question, it led into the right direction (and thus is *even better* than an answer). It's certainly true that downgrading any document to a lower version is or might be dangerous.

The problem is, however, that `\pdfminorversion` only works for PdfTeX and not LuaTeX.

According to [the answers found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374991/lualatex-and-pdfminorversion) for LuaTeX (and likely XeTeX, I didn't check), you have to set in the preamble of a project either

```
\pdfvariable minorversion=6
```

or

```
\directlua{pdf.setminorversion(6)}
```

(the latter is not likely to work with XeTeX).

So I still don't know how to *effectively* (versus *theoretically* – if someone knows an answer to this he is still wellcome) downgrade a PDF, but nontheless my actual problem is solved.